# Unquoted "raw" Ansible variable in YAML output

Tags: ansible, yaml

Given this template:

```yaml
enabled: "{{ some_var }}"
```

And this variable definition:

```yaml
some_var: true
```

How do I create a file from the template with the following output (notice there are no quotes):

```yaml
enabled: true
```

Since curly braces must be quoted when they're at the beginning, currently I get `enabled: "true"`.
`{{ some_var | bool }}` also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your template as below:

```yaml
enabled: {{ some_var | string | lower }}
```

Comment: Right, I got confused with having to quote curly braces in Ansible tasks. In a template you can just write whatever haha. Thanks.